# Sorting program in C

Tags: c, sorting

I am new to C, and I have no habit to use such objects like 'struct'. I am trying to improving the speed of a simple program : Suppose the input is made of two lists : one of N elements, and another of M elements. I want to know for each elements of the second list, if it appears in the first list, the output is then 1, and if not the return is then 0. Finally, The output appears in the order the second list's elements were input.

So I tried first to order both lists with qsort() and then compare each list but my program outputs aberrant results. For example, if I fix M to 2, I have an output of 4 numbers ! So here's my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//this function detects if the element 'input' is appears in the 
//first list called 'c'
//The output returns 0 if not, and the '(i+1)th' place 'input' 
//appears in 'c'

int search(int input,int a, int N,int c[N]){
    int i;
    int res=0;



for(i=a;i<N;i++){
        if(input==c[N-1-i]){res=i+1;break;}
        else{}
    }
    return res;
}

//Since we sort each list and since we want the output to appear 
//in the order each element  the second list's elements were input,
//we define a 'Spec' to keep in mind each index of the second list's 
//elements
struct Spec{
    int val;
    int ind;
};

//function qsort() uses to sort the first list 'c'
int compare (int* a, int* b)
{
    return ( *a - *b );
}

//function qsort() uses to sort the second list called 'd'
int comp(const void* a, const void* b)
{

    const struct Spec *A = (const struct Spec*) a;
    const struct Spec *B = (const struct Spec*) b;
    return A->val - B->val;
}

int main()
{
    int i;

    //the size of the first list 'c'
    int N;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    int rank=0;

    //declaring and sorting the first list 'c'
    int c[N];
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {scanf("%d", &c[i]);}
    qsort (c, N, sizeof(int),compare);

    //the size of the second list 'd'
    int M;
    scanf("%d",&M);

    //declaring and sorting the second list 'd'
    struct Spec* d;
    d = (struct Spec*)calloc(M, sizeof(struct Spec));
    for(i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {scanf("%d", &d[i].val);}

    //initialize the index of the input's elements order 
    for(i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {d[i].ind=i;}

    qsort (d, N, sizeof(struct Spec), comp);

    //the output will be stored in 'f'
    int f[M];


    //if the following condition is verified, the the output must 
    //always be 0
    if((d[0].val>c[N-1])||(d[M-1].val<c[0])){
        for(i=0;i<M;i++){printf("0");printf("\n");}
    }


    else{
    for (i=0;i<M;i++){

        //the output is stored in 'f', and the index to respect 
        //input's order is then 'd[i].ind'
        if((d[i].val<c[0])){f[d[i].ind]=0;}
        //if the following condition is verified, the the output must always be 0 for the last 'M-i' outputs


        else if((d[i].val>c[N-1]))
             {
             int j;
             for(j=i;j<M;j++)
                {
                f[d[j].ind]=0;
                }
             break;
             }


        else{
                //if an element 'd[i]' of the second list 'd' 
                //appears in the first list 'c', then the output 
                //stored in 'f' will be '1' and the size of the 
                //matching (betwenn 'c' and 'd') search can be 
                //truncated from the first 'rank-1' elements
                if(search(d[i].val,rank,N,c)>0){
                rank=search(d[i].val,rank,N,c)-1;
                f[d[i].ind]=1;
                }
            else{f[d[i].ind]=0;}
            }
       }
    }

    //printing the output
    for(i=0;i<M;i++){
        printf("%d",f[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Could anyone help ?

Comment: Why bother sorting the second list?  It makes sense to sort the first list, then for each element in the 2nd list, do a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) to see if it exists in the first.  I'm not convinced you need structs for this.

Comment: qsort the first list, then use binary search in place of your existing search() method.  Binary search is much much faster than the brute force method.

Comment: Also, I really want to understand better Struct :)

Comment: Your code will be much easier to read if you don't inline some much of it.  This line for example `else if((d[i].val>c[N-1])){int j;for(j=i;j<M;j++){f[d[j].ind]=0;}break;}` is screaming for proper formatting.

Comment: One thing I noticed (not sure if it's the problem): you declare d to have M elements, but then you call qsort with N as the parameter.

Comment: Thank you, it was a copy-paste problem. The code is still going wrong

Comment: If you need to output the verdicts in the order in which the second list is presented, you probably only want to sort the first list, and then use a linear scan of the second list, using binary search to find the values (or not) in the first list.  If you're allowed to use the C library, then the standard C functions `qsort()` and `bsearch()` are designed to help with this task.  This will give you an O(N log N) complexity solution (the sort is O(N log N) and you do N searches where each search is O(log N), so that is O(N log N) too).

Comment: I made some changes, now my algo works fine, but is sure not optimized, I 'll take a look in binary search

Answer (score 1):

Your problem - as stated in your post of extra output - is caused by the placement of the print loop. You should move it inside of that last "else" statement.

You first test if all elements of D are outside (bigger or smaller) of all elements in C. If so, print all zeros. That's fine but then at the end you again print F which is where the extra output comes from.

Now, to work on your code formatting......

Answer (score 0):

To speed up the code, replace the existing search() function with a [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Also, take a look at the line of code `if((d[i].val<c[0])){f[d[i].ind]=0;}` and verify you wish to compare against `c[0]` instead of `c[i]`.

Comment: No, since I am comparing d[i].val with the lower value of c, d[i].val could not be found in the array

Comment: I made some changes, now my algo works fine, but is sure not optimized, I 'll take a look in binary search. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reading your description and the source code you provided it appears that you are doing the following actions.

First of all you read in a list of values that are a kind of constant that you want to know if they appear in another list.  This is the SearchFor list.

Next you read in a list of values that you want to know how many and which of these in the second list are also in the first list.  This is the ValueExist list.

To make the search procedure easier, you sort the list of SearchFor values so that when you are comparing a particular item in the ValueExist list as soon as you either find a match or you find that the current item in the SearchFor list you are comparing with the current item in the ValueExist list is less than the current item in the ValueExist list you have either found a match, if they are equal, or the value in the ValueExist list is not in the SearchFor list because the current comparison item in the SearchFor list is less than the value of the current item in the ValueExist list.

So the routine for doing the matching would look something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//this function detects if the element 'input' is appears in the 
//first list called 'c'
//The output returns 0 if not, and the '(i+1)th' place 'input' 
//appears in 'c'

//Since we sort each list and since we want the output to appear 
//in the order each element  the second list's elements were input,
//we define a 'Spec' to keep in mind each index of the second list's 
//elements
struct Spec {
    int iValue;
    int iIndex;
};

//function qsort() uses to sort the first list 'c'
int compare (void *a, void *b)
{
    return ( *(int *)a - *(int *)b );
}

//function qsort() uses to sort the second list called 'd'
int comp(const void* a, const void* b)
{

    const struct Spec *A = (const struct Spec*) a;
    const struct Spec *B = (const struct Spec*) b;
    return (A->iValue - B->iValue);
}

int main()
{
    int i, iExist;

    //the size of the first list 'c'
    int N;
    printf ("Enter number of values for SearchFor list\n");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    int rank=N;

    //declaring and sorting the first list 'c'
    int SearchFor[N];
    for(i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        printf ("Enter value for index %d\n", i);
        scanf("%d", &SearchFor[i]);
    }
   qsort (SearchFor, N, sizeof(int), compare);

    //the size of the second list 'd'
    int M;
    printf ("\nEnter number of values to search for\n");
    scanf("%d",&M);

    //declaring and sorting the second list 'd'
    struct Spec* ValueExist = (struct Spec*)calloc(M, sizeof(struct Spec));
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        // remember the original index for this value
        ValueExist[i].iIndex = i;
        // get the value for this index
        printf ("Enter value for index %d\n", i);
        scanf("%d", &ValueExist[i].iValue);
    }

    qsort (ValueExist, M, sizeof(struct Spec), comp);

    for (iExist = 0; iExist < M; iExist++) {
       for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
          if (ValueExist[iExist].iValue == SearchFor[i]) {
             // value found
             printf ("Value of %d at index %d found.\n", ValueExist[iExist].iValue, ValueExist[iExist].iIndex);
             break;
           } else if (ValueExist[iExist].iValue < SearchFor[i]) {
              break;
           }
        }
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

your code can not be compiled successfully,because "N" can not be vari int c[N];

Comment: Variable length arrays were introduced in C99.